# Maven 3 is looking for maven-metadata.xml in the wrong folder (Artifactory 2.5.1.1)

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-metadata

```
[08:45:24]Downloading: http://maven-proxy.xxx.local:8081/artifactory/xxx-snapshots/xxx/xxx/xxx/some-lib/1.2.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[08:45:24][DEBUG] Could not find metadata xxx.xxx.xxx:some-lib:1.2.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in xxx-snapshots (http://maven-proxy.xxx.local:8081/artifactory/xxx-snapshots)
```

Maven seems to be looking for a metadata file in `some-lib/1.2.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml`. There is however a `maven-metadata.xml` file residing in `some-lib/maven-metadata.xml`.

What might be wrong? Should this file be generated by Artifactory or is something wrong with the deployment?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Either you have a wrong dependency or your settings.xml is not correctly configured.

Answer (score 2):

Maven metadata may reside on 2 levels:

1. Under the *groupId/artifactId* folders - the metadata details which base revisions exist (1.0, 1.1, 1.2-SNAPSHOT, etc.)
2. Under the *groupId/artifactId/integrationRevision* folders - the metadata details which specific integration revisions exist;

The latter is needed because Maven's snapshot version may aggregate a number of different unique snapshots. so when requesting 1.0-SNAPSHOT, Maven must discover which actual snapshots exist and determine which one to download.

This metadata should be auto-generated by the repository, only of such snapshot versions exist.

Comment: Okay, so the `xxx/some-lib/1.2.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml` file should be generated by Artifactory?

Comment: If a snapshot revision exists and is deployed to a snapshot repository, then yes.

Comment: Sure? I tried deleting the repository from Artifactory and re-deploy it to see if that helped. 
`Uploaded: http://maven-proxy.xxx.local:8081/artifactory/xxx-snapshots/xxx/xxx/xxx/some-lib/1.2.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 50.1 KB/sec)`, but when I attempt to access the very same address I get a 404 - metadata not found for...

Comment: Positive. Depending on the repository's snapshot policy, Artifactory basically ignores Maven's deploy requests and calculates the metadata by itself; but it should be there.

Comment: Then something is probably messed up with the Artifactory installation. I semi-fixed it by configuring the snapshot repository to "deployer" instead of "unique", but I guess that's just one Maven 2 client away from blowing up again.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer on gradle.org](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-find-metadata-maven-metadata-xml-in-remote/11720/2),

The `maven-metadata.xml` won't exist yet when you publishing a `SNAPSHOT` version for the **first time**.

(Subsequent uploads should not display this message since the first publish should create the file.)